How to embed a Tweet/X Post into Angular page?
I'd like to have this post on my Angular v13+ page.

First tried the top 2 solution of Twitter embedded for Angular 2, not working.
Then follow X's document, click on the post, r-click on the three-dot at upper right, pick Embed post, either option, copy and paste the code into my template. Because the code contains http://t.co... not allowed in body here by SO, here is where you can copy the code:
https://x.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E463440424141459456%7Ctwgr%5E336184b268d6d40d67e98771bafb611b1bfbbf77%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.x.com%2Fen%2Fdocs%2Ftwitter-for-websites%2Fembedded-tweets%2Foverview
Result is only the text

Maybe security? Don't think so, but added connect-src 'self' https://twitter.com to index.html still not help.
